# React jQuery does not recognize element as Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

**Goal:** to access Bootstrap Modal's `modal()` code in React.

There is a React app with a Bootstrap v4.

*package.json*:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.6"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now trying to get `modal()` via Chrome Dev Tools gives:

[image]

So it seems like:

- It *can* see jQuery;
- It *can't* recognize `foo` Modal as Bootstrap's `modal()`;

How to make jQuery recognize `foo` as the `modal()`?

Comment: As an alternative, you can check out reactstrap (https://reactstrap.github.io/). It contains components designed for React.

Comment: click is a function so use click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what's your expectation. But if you want to get an element as bootstrap modal object, you have to call the modal at least one time as initialization. Please check my codes snippet bellow:

```js
$('.show-modal-btn').on('click', () => {
  let yourModalEl = $('#your-modal');
  console.log(yourModalEl.data('bs.modal')); // will be undefined
  yourModalEl.modal();
  console.log(yourModalEl.data('bs.modal')); // modal object
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="modal fade" id="your-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="show-modal-btn">Init modal</button>
```

Comment: Good catch. I've got where I was wrong - supposed to init the element first.